# c function returns an error - how to exit program

Tags: c, return

I call 4 functions in my `main` that `return 0` for success and `return -1` for failure. If any of them fail I do not want to call the next functions, just print an error statement and exit.

How could I implement this?

```
int main(void)
{
deviceSync();
deviceInit();
devicesettings();
devicetakemeasurement();
}
```

Comment: How could you write external functions without knowing if/else ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't understand programming at all

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#define FAILURE -1

int main() {
    if ( FAILURE == deviceSync() ) {
        fputs("Device Sync failed\n",stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( FAILURE == deviceInit() ) {
        fputs("Device Init failed\n",stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( FAILURE == devicesettings() ) {
        fputs("Device setting failed\n",stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ( FAILURE == devicetakemeasurement() ) {
        fputs("Device take measurement failed\n",stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: By convention a C program returns the predefined values `EXIT_FAILURE` on failure and `EXIT_SUCCESS` on success.

Comment: However +1 for being the only answer so far sticking to the specs, that is testing the functions against `-1`!

Comment: @alk You are right, updated (hopefuly in the right way). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run an if statement for each of the functions

```
int main(void)
{
    if(deviceSync())return -1;
    if(deviceInit())return -1;
    //...
}
```

This will return -1 when a function returns non-zero

Edit: sorry, I shouldn't have put the 'nots' on there

Comment: `!deviceSync()` is indeed success

Comment: You are treating a status code as a boolean, making the code hard to understand.  `if( deviceSync() != 0 ) { ... }` would be much more clear.

Comment: The code does not just test against `-1` but against everything different from `0`, which makes the error logging ambiguous.